# Dirac operator on a 5 dimensional tangent manifold with a $Spin(3)$-bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, spin-geometry, dirac-operator

In [p.3 of Witten paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/0370-2693(82)90728-6) from this [Physics Letters B, Volume 117, Issue 5, 18 November 1982, Pages 324-328 Physics Letters B, 117(5), 324–328](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(82)90728-6), he says that about the Dirac equation on a 5-dimensional
tangent space manifold locally with $O(5)$ tangent bundle and with an extra $Spin(3)=SU(2)$-bundle.

[image]

### My concerns

- He said the gamma matrices $\gamma^i$ to be real, symmetric 8 X 8 matrices

**question 1:** why these $\gamma^i$ not 4 X 4 matrices for Dirac operator on the 5 dimension space? Note that we only need 4 X 4 matrices, not 8 X 8 matrices?

**question 2:** why $\gamma^i$ are real? why symmetric?

- He said the anti-hermitian generators $T^a$ of $SU(2)=Spin(3)$ are real, anti-symmetric matrices

**question 3:** I agree $T^a$ are anti-hermitian. But why $T^a$ are real? thus anti-symmetric? (Of course, if $T^a$ is real and anti-hermitian, then $T^a$ has to be anti-symmetric.)

Naivel, the anti-hermitian generators 2 X 2 matrices of SU(2) are pseudoreal as:
$$
i \sigma_1 =i \sigma_\mathrm{x} =
 i   \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 i \sigma_2 =i \sigma_\mathrm{y} =
   i \begin{pmatrix}
      0& -i \\
      i&0
    \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 i \sigma_3 = i\sigma_\mathrm{z} =
   i \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&-1
    \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: The $8$-dimensional real Clifford algebra has two simple real representations of dimension $8+8$, one being the parity reversal of the other. The $\gamma$-matrices that Witten uses are the first $5$ of the $8$ $8\times 8$-matrices which encode the action of the generators of the Clifford algebra in a suitable basis. Similarly, the $T^a$ generate the commuting $SO(3)$-action, which is also defined via real matrices. He also cites the relevant fact from representation theory: the tensor product of two pseudo-real/quaternionic representations has a canonical real structure.

Comment: Thanks so much for comments!